Href is not change or load. Can't figure out why
function generatePagination(currentPage, totalPages, pageURLs) {
  const paginationContainer = document.getElementById('pagination');
  paginationContainer.innerHTML = '';

  // Previous Page Link
  const prevLi = document.createElement('li');
  const prevA = document.createElement('a');
  prevA.href = currentPage > 1 ? pageURLs[currentPage - 2] : '#';
  prevA.textContent = 'Previous';
  prevLi.appendChild(prevA);
  paginationContainer.appendChild(prevLi);

  const startPage = Math.max(1, currentPage - 2);
  const endPage = Math.min(totalPages, startPage + 4);

  for (let i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = pageURLs[i - 1]; // Adjust index since pages start from 1
    a.textContent = i;
    if (i === currentPage) {
      li.classList.add('active');
    }
    a.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of the link
      generatePagination(i, totalPages, pageURLs);
    });

    li.appendChild(a);
    paginationContainer.appendChild(li);
  }

  // Next Page Link
  const nextLi = document.createElement('li');
  const nextA = document.createElement('a');
  nextA.href = currentPage < totalPages ? pageURLs[currentPage] : '#';
  nextA.textContent = 'Next';
  nextLi.appendChild(nextA);
  paginationContainer.appendChild(nextLi);
}

// Example usage:
// Assuming current page is 3 and total pages is 10
// and pageURLs is an array of URLs for each page
const pageURLs = [
  '/HTML/index.html',
  '/HTML/mp/2.html',
  '/HTML/mp/3.html',
  '/HTML/mp/4.html',
  '/HTML/mp/5.html',
  '/HTML/mp/6.html',
  '/HTML/mp/7.html',
  '/HTML/mp/8.html',
  '/HTML/mp/9.html',

  // Add URLs for other pages here
];
generatePagination(1, 10, pageURLs);

I got stuck for href is not change when i click to the page. if i fixed the href change or load then the active a is not working.
Can someone please help.

when i try this:
a.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of the link
  generatePagination(i, totalPages, pageURLs);
});

the active a working, but when i delete this the href is working but active a is not work.`

Please post the code as text, not images
